# How to gather points that can be directly connected with respect to buildings?

Tags: python, gis, openstreetmap, raycasting, geopy

So I want  to do something like this:

[image]

Based on this [sample](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/develop/notebooks/L6/retrieve_osm_data.html) I was able to draw OSM maps and add points based on [this one](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2017/lessons/L3/point-in-polygon.html).

I wonder how to throw rays between points and see if they intersect with OSM buildings?

Answer (score 1):

First you would want OSM data in vector format where you can get building information in vector form.
You may try this source: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/osm-vector-tiles.html
Connect points with Line features and use intersect operation to find if any buildings intersect with this lines.